# No option for ConcatMap with skip error - RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

Consider this example:
I have a file downloading in sequence. If one download fails, it should move to next.
Psudo code:

```
Observable.from(urls)
 .concatMap(url -> downloadObservable(url))
```

There is no option for moving to next url if the download fails.

There is no way to skip with `onErrorResumeNext()` as I just want to move to next url. Can anyone help?

Comment: what does `downloadObservable(url)` return?

Comment: @ESala It return api call Observable for that url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an operator for this: `concatMapDelayError` since 1.3. In general, if there is a reason errors could be delayed until all sources have been consumed fully, there is likely a `opNameDelayError` operator for it.

```
Observable.from(urls)
    .concatMapDelayError(url -> downloadObservable(url))
    .doOnError(error -> {
        if (error instanceof CompositeException) {
           System.out.println(((CompositeException)error).getExceptions().size());
        } else {
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    });
```

(The `doOnError` addendum comes from the updated OP's [cross post](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5787#issuecomment-355527270) on the RxJava issue list.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What to do if I want to get url of failed download after this?

Comment: You could collect the failed urls in a separate side-list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RxJava 1, a quick and dirty solution is to return `null` when the download fails and then filter them out:

```
Observable
    .from(urls)
    .concatMap(url -> downloadObservable(url).onErrorReturn(null))
    .filter(result -> result != null)
```

A nicer solution would be to create a wrapper for the result having a method like `wasSuccessful()` for checking in the filter and a method like `getResult()` for extracting the result from the wrapper. This way you don't have to handle nulls.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3870 there is no way to do this. Of course you can introduce some other error handling, i.e. handle error inside downloadObservable then filter null answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think that is a pipeline so, in case you don't want to stop the emission of the pipeline, you have to control the error and return something in order to continue with the next emission.

The only way to use onErrorResumeNext and not stop the emission after that, is if it´s executed in a flatMap

```
Observable.from(urls)
 .flatMap(url -> downloadObservable(url)
                   .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.just("Something went wrong"))))
```

You can see an example here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/errors/ObservableExceptions.java